# Apex.db file gets added automatically

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, salesforce-communities

While pushing a class to bitbucket using Sourcetree . I got this file apex.db added automatically alone with the class. Am not able to discard or Remove it.

[image: This is the screenshot]

I tried clicking on discard and Remove. But still was not able to remove

Please let me know What is this  Apex.db file. Why is it not able to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Got it . Just a try to uninstall and reinstall sourcetree.
And create a new folder for Source.